# SELECT, PROJECT, CARTESIAN PRODUCT and JOIN

Tags: join, select

I have the following tables;

```
DOG    +----------------------------------------------+
       | Name   Type     Age Kennel_name  Owner_name  |
       +----------------------------------------------+
       | Rover  Labrador 4   Bidawee      Smith       |
       | Lassie Alsatian 3   Rescue Dogs  Jones       |
       +----------------------------------------------+

OWNER  +------------------+
       | Name  City       |
       +------------------+
       | Smith Lancaster  |
       | Jones Nottingham |
       +------------------+

KENNEL +-----------------------+
       |   Name        City    |
       +-----------------------+
       | Bidawee     Preston   |
       | Rescue Dogs Sheffield |
       +-----------------------+
```

I am struggling to understand what the following would do to these tables;

```
i) select (using DOG)
ii) project (using DOG)
iii) Cartesian product (using DOG and OWNER)
iv) join (using DOG and OWNER)
```

My understanding is that;

```
i)   Would simply produce the DOG table again.
ii)  Would produce the DOG table again but ensure there are no duplicate values in the resulting table.
iii) Would produce a table where every value of DOG also ties up to Owner
iv)  I am unsure really what join would do here, would it simply just join DOG and Owner together and add the Name and City fields from OWNER onto the end of DOG?
```

Could somebody please explain these a bit further and correct me if I have any of them wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your understanding seems mostly correct. i) two rows, 5 columns. ii) it depends on the desired attributes, which you haven't provided. iii) 4 rows, 7 columns. iv) the join would happen on dog.owner_name and owner.name presumably and the result would be 2 rows, 7 columns. Is this a homework problem for relational algebra or database design? I'm wondering if that's why your question is abstract instead of tied to a specific technology.

Comment: It's actually revision for a database exam, thanks for the answers :) I guess for ii) If the attributes aren't desired, we simply project the DOG table again minus any repeating values should there be any?

Comment: According to my old database design text, "project produces a subset of the columns ... Project uses a list of column names to indicate the columns to retain in the output ... Project: an operator that retrieves a specified subset of the columns of the input table." So to me, that means you need a column list, and without it, then it's the same as the select operator.